# Is it possible to add refresh control below section header

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with section header. I want to add refresh control below the section header and not at top of tableview.Is this possible??

Comment: You could make the first cell of the section contain a uibutton that reloads the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.It is not possible.Try adding an activity indicator in the section header.
If u want the activity indicator to be shown only when the user pulls down while tableview content offset is 0, then try adding a pan gesture and implementing it only for this specific condition

```
        var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedDown))
    self.HometableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    panGesture.delegate = self as! UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

//The code to handle the pan gesture

```
func swipedDown(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let velocity: CGPoint = panGesture.velocity(in: HometableView)
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        print("gesture moving Up")
        if(HometableView.contentOffset == CGPoint.zero)
        {
            print("************SWIPED DOWN")
            //Do the logic to increase section header height and show the activity indicator

        }

    }
    else {
        print("gesture moving Bottom")



    }


}

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    let velocity: CGPoint = panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: HometableView)
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        if(HometableView.contentOffset == CGPoint.zero)
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible as the section header is part of tableView.

You can add the view not as a part of section header but at the top of  UITableView.